# Diamond schema: how (de)normalized is that?

Tags: sql, database, schema, normalization

Let's suppose we have the following entities:

- Production Studio
- Journalist
- Camera Operator
- News Footage

In this simple world, production studio has many journalists and many camera operators. Each journalist belongs to exactly one studio. Same thing with operators. A news footage is produced by one journalist and one operator, where both come from the same studio.

Here's my naive approach to put this model into relational database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE production_studios(
  id                   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title                TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE journalists(
  id                   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name                 TEXT NOT NULL,
  prodution_studio_id  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES production_studios
);

CREATE TABLE camera_operators(
  id                   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name                 TEXT NOT NULL,
  production_studio_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES production_studios
);

CREATE TABLE news_footages(
  id                   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  description          TEXT NOT NULL,
  journalist_id        INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES journalists,
  camera_operator_id   INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES camera_operators
);
```

This schema forms nicely shaped diamond ERD and a few questions.

The problem is that news footage can link together a journalist with a camera operator which come from different production studios. I understand that this can be cured by writing corresponding constraints, but for the sake of experiment let's pretend that we're doing exercise in Normal Form database design.

1. The first question is about terminology: is it correct to state that this schema is denormalized? If yes, which normal form does it break? Or is there any better name for this anomaly, like inter-record redundancy, multipath relationships, etc?
2. How this schema can be changed to make described anomaly impossible?

And of course I'd very much appreciate references to papers addressing this specific issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The naive way would be to make your journalists and camera_operators *dependent entities*, dependent upon the studio for which they work. That means the production studio foreign key becomes part of their primary key. Your news_footage table then has a primary key consisting of 4 components:

- production_studio_id
- journalist_id
- camera_operator_id
- footage_id

and two foreign keys:

- journalist_id,production_studio_id, pointing to the journalist table, and
- camera_operator,production_studio_id, pointing to the camera operator table

Easy.

**Or Not.** Now you have defined in your E-R model the notion that the very **existence** of a camera operator or a journalist is dependent upon the studio for which they work. This does not reflect the real work very well: in this model, people can't change their employer.

Let's not do that.

In your original model, you confusing a *person* with a _role they play (journalist or camera operator), and you're missing a somewhat transient entity that is actually responsible for the production of your news footage: the [studio-specific] production team.

My E-R model would look something like this:

```
create table studio
(
  id int not null primary key ,
  title varchar(200) not null ,
)

create table person
(
  id int not null primary key ,
  title varchar(200) not null ,
)

create table team
(
  studio_id          int not null ,
  journalist_id      int not null ,
  camera_operator_id int not null ,

  primary key ( studio_id , journalist_id , camera_operator ) ,

  foreign key ( studio_id          ) references studio ( id ) ,
  foreign key ( journalist_id      ) references person ( id ) ,
  foreign key ( camera_operator_id ) references person ( id ) ,

)

create table footage
(
  studio_id          int not null ,
  journalist_id      int not null ,
  camera_operator_id int not null ,
  id                 int not null ,
  description        varchar(200) not null ,

  primary key ( studio_id , journalist_id , camera_operator_id , id ) ,

  foreign key     ( studio_id , journalist_id , camera_operator_id )
  references team ( studio_id , journalist_id , camera_operator_id ) ,

)
```

Now you have a world in which people can work in different *roles*: the same person might be a camera operator in some contexts and a journalist in others. People can change employers. Studio-specific teams are composed, consisting of a journalist and a camera operator. In some contexts, the same person might play both roles on a team. And, finally, a piece of news footage is produced by one and only one studio-specific team.

This reflects the real world much better, and it is much more flexible.

Edited to add sample query:

To find the journalists working for a particular studio:

```
select p.*
from studio s
join team   t on t.studio_id = s.id
join person p on p.id        = t.journalist_id
where s.title = 'my desired studio name'
```

This would give you the set of people who are (or have) been associated with a studio in the role of journalist. One should note though, that in the real world, people work for employers for a period of time: to model it properly  you need a start/end date and you need to qualify the query with a relative notion of now.

Comment: You're making perfect points. Indeed I've missed person and his/her role.

Comment: You're making perfect points, thank you. Indeed I've missed person and his/her role. However now, the only way for a journalist to belong to a studio is to form a team with operator. Let's say that journalists (and operators) are employed by studios (that was expressed by FKs in my example). Given this new schema, how do I find which journalists are employed by particular studio?

Comment: @SergeBalyuk: see my amended answer.

Comment: One issue with this approach - with the loss of journalist and camera operator tables, you lose a location for columns specific to those roles (e.g. equipment training information for a camera operator that you wouldn't want in person).

Comment: @Reinderien: _journalist_ and _camera operator_ can be looked at as subtypes of _person_. To carry attributes specific to such a subtype, you create tables whose primary key is a `person_id` that is a foreign key to the Person table, having a zero-to-one cardinality with person. If a person is, say, a camera operator, then the camera operator table will have and entry for that person. That way, Person carries the common attributes and the subtype tables carry those attributes specific to the subtype.

Comment: @Nicholas I agree, but that carries another problem - the database won't complain if you create a person row representing a journalist, and then relate to it from a camera operator row.

Comment: @Reinderien: Why should there be? In the real world, one may be both a reporter and a photographer. Relational databases have a certain impedance mismatch with object models. And the constraint system in a relational db simply can't express every possible rule. However, StackOverflow is not for carrying a dialog in the comments section. But thanks for the thoughts.